# Context in echo v4

Tags: go, go-gin, go-echo

When I made a request with context

```
req, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, method, url, payload)
```

Then, if I check the context in the service I can see the context I've sent. For example, in an api that employs gin gonic framework, I got the context I sent using:

```
c.Request.Context()
```

However, in an api that employs echo/v4 if I use

```
c.Request().Context()
```

I got a context but it isn't the context I sent.

I'm expecting obatain the context I've sent in a echo api.

I added this image, this is the ctx I'm sending.

[Context I sent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPoah.png)

When I inspect the ctxt in a second service which receives the context. Using gin I got that context:

[In Gin API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSDYg.png)

However in echo I got this:

[In Echo API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGhWQ.png)

Comment: What do you mean with "same context"? How do you check?

Comment: I running locally two services. One service sent a request to the other. That request is with context. The second service must receive the context, but  it doesn't (for echo case), if I use gin it works. I'm checking by inspect the variables.

Comment: You should not expect `ctx` to equal `c.Request.Context()` or `c.Request().Context()` when the HTTP method is executed over a network.

Comment: A guess at the problem: The Gin server application uses the OpenTelemetry middleware.  The Echo server application does not use  OpenTelemetry middleware.

Comment: From the screenshots, it looks like Echo wraps a cancel context around your context, so that it can cancel the request gracefully. There is no promise that the service will receive the exact same context that the client passes (if the request goes over HTTP, then this is even physically impossible). I wouldn't be surprised in the Echo case if the request isn't the same pointer as the one you passed in either.

Comment: 0


Contexts are not intended to pass info from client to server. (If gin does this, it's a bug.) You need to use a header or the request body.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot provide an explanation for why gin appears to see a context that looks like the one you are sending, but your expectation of how `http.Request.ctx` - what is returned by `http.Request.Context()` - is incorrect.  If you want to pass additional information between an HTTP client and server, you have to do that using mechanisms supported by HTTP - which are the request body, request parameters, and request headers.  Both gin and echo even have their own internal `Context` types used to carry information through the call stack, which only makes things more confusing.

If you look at [the library code which actually writes out the http request](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.5:src/net/http/request.go;drc=5454834f011c019ca32d844d26d469cd47f407ad;l=555), you will see that it makes no use of the key/value capabilities of a golang `context.Context`.

It really only appears to be used [here](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.5:src/net/http/request.go;drc=5454834f011c019ca32d844d26d469cd47f407ad;l=555) where the `RoundTripper` checks if the request's context has timed out before completion, in which case (as one would expect) an error is returned.

So I think you need to recalibrate your expectations of what you can do with request contexts in HTTP and use one of the supported mechanisms to pass whatever it is you need to pass.